# Can this be tail call optimized? If so, what's the special reason for it not happen?

Tags: c++, tail-recursion

I've checked assembly output at many optimization levels with both gcc 4.8.1 and clang 3.4.190255, no tail call optimization for this kind of code.

Any special reason why `collatz_aux` doesn't get a tail call optimization?

```
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

vector<unsigned> concat(vector<unsigned> v, unsigned n) {
    v.push_back(n);
    return v;
}

vector<unsigned> collatz_aux(unsigned n, vector<unsigned> result) {
    return n == 1
        ? result
        : n % 2 == 0
            ? collatz_aux(n / 2, concat(move(result), n))
            : collatz_aux(3 * n + 1, concat(move(result), n));
}

vector<unsigned> collatz_vec(unsigned n) {
    assert(n != 0);
    return collatz_aux(n, {});
}

int main() {
    return collatz_vec(10).size();
}
```

Comment: Related, maybe duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17792887/can-tail-call-optimization-and-raii-co-exist

Comment: I really don't understand the point of the `concat` function.  This would be significantly simpler (and probably enable tail recursion) if you simply used an iterator.  In fact, when I try, it makes it obvious how the code can be easily rewritten.

Comment: Iterator variant: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/24bd251ace479632

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The destructor for the `vector<unsigned>` parameter needs to be called after the return.

Answer (score 2):

Just for reference, I tweaked the recursive version, to get tail recursion, to this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

template<class container>
container &&collatz_aux(unsigned n, container &&result) {
    static auto concat = [](container &&c, unsigned n) -> container &&{
        c.push_back(n);
        return forward<container>(c);
    };

    return n == 1
        ? forward<container>(result)
        : n % 2 == 0
            ? collatz_aux(n / 2, concat(forward<container>(result), n))
            : collatz_aux(3 * n + 1, concat(forward<container>(result), n));
}

vector<unsigned> collatz_vec(unsigned n) {
    assert(n != 0);
    return collatz_aux(n, vector<unsigned>{});
}

int main() {
    return collatz_vec(10).size();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be relying on tail-call for this. I would think it unlikely that the optimiser is going to spot that **both** recursive calls can be tail-optimised.

Here's a non-recursive version.

```
vector<unsigned> collatz_aux(unsigned n, vector<unsigned> result) {
  while(true){
    if(n == 1) return result;
    result = concat(move(result), n);
    if(n % 2 == 0)
    {
      n=n / 2;
    }else{
      n= 3 * n + 1;
    }
  }
}
```