# Does shared pointer break tail call optimization?

Tags: c++, recursion, shared-ptr, compiler-optimization, tail-recursion

## Preface

I'm practicing C++ and trying to implement immutable list.
In one of my tests I'm trying to create a list with lot of values (1 million nodes) recursively. All values are `const`, so I cannot perform regular loop, also this isn't *functional* enough, you know.
The test fails with `Segmentation fault`.

My system is 64-bit Xubuntu 16.04 LTS with Linux 4.4.
I compile the my code with g++ 5.4 and clang++ 3.8 using `--std=c++14 -O3` flags.

## Source code

I've written a simple example, which shows the situation, when tail call should be easily optimized, but something goes wrong and `Segmentation fault` appears. The function `f` just waits `amount` iterations and then creates a pointer to single `int` and returns it

```
#include <memory>

using std::shared_ptr;

shared_ptr<int> f(unsigned amount) {
    return amount? f(amount - 1) : shared_ptr<int>{new int};
}

int main() {
    return f(1E6) != nullptr;
}
```

**Note** this example fails only with `g++`, while `clang++` makes it okay.
Though, on more complicated example it doesn't optimize too.

Here is an example of a simple list with recursive insertion of elements.
Also I've added `destroy` function, which helps to avoid stack overflow during destruction.
Here I get `Segmentation fault` with both compilers

```
#include <memory>

using std::shared_ptr;

struct L {
    shared_ptr<L> tail;

    L(const L&) = delete;
    L() = delete;
};

shared_ptr<L> insertBulk(unsigned amount, const shared_ptr<L>& tail) {
    return amount? insertBulk(amount - 1, shared_ptr<L>{new L{tail}})
                 : tail;
}

void destroy(shared_ptr<L> list) {
    if (!list) return;

    shared_ptr<L> tail = list->tail;
    list.reset();

    for (; tail; tail = tail->tail);
}

int main() {
    shared_ptr<L> list = shared_ptr<L>{new L{nullptr}};
    destroy(insertBulk(1E6, list));
    return 0;
}
```

**NOTE**
Implementation with regular pointers is optimized well by both compilers.

## Question

Does `shared_ptr` really break tail call optimization in my case?
Is it a compilers' issue or a problem with `shared_ptr` implementation?

Comment: " but I guess that this example is more clear with USE_SHARED_PTR macros." - not.

Comment: @NeilButterworth thanks, I've written more simple example

Comment: looks like you construct a new instance of the shared_ptr wrapper for each level. Try reference?

Comment: @KennyOstrom yes, reference made its job, so I've changed the example in order to show the problem more realistically.

Comment: Why do you use `shared_ptr` instead of `unique_ptr`? Do you plan to let multiple lists share the same tail, since they are immutable?

Comment: @DanielH yes, that's exactly what I want to do

Comment: @Charlie I deleted my answer as the question has changed too much.  But the problem seems to be that it's very easy to create temps with c++ that prevent tail call elimination.  Paste your code into godbolt.org to see what code is getting created.  This may be closer to what you want: `return amount? insertBulk(amount - 1, tail) : shared_ptr<L>{tail}`

Comment: @TonyLee I'm using `-S` option of my compiler in order to get assembly code and I see that it makes a lot of stuff after recursive call

Comment: @TonyLee no, your example will create a new pointer to `tail`, but I want to create a new list, which has its tail equal to `tail` parameter of the function. It's an `insert` function, not `copy` :)

Comment: @Charlie - I think I understand now - this is a pretty interesting problem with shared_ptr and c++'s deterministic destruction.  It's beyond me to solve.

Comment: You are specifically commanding the compiler to create a new object at each recursion level (until the inevitable stack overflow). I don't see how tail recursion would be possible. In contrast, a simple pointer can be passed by value, or used in a loop, which is basically what tail recursion is, I thought. The recursive function could be a hidden helper, and you can make the shared_ptr in a wrapper.

Comment: @KennyOstrom I didn't get the idea of a hidden helper and wrapper you mean

Comment: I'm saying you don't need a shared pointer inside of a recursion/iteration you control. One function can be the public interface (wrapper) and call the recursive function. The recursive function has a simple POD type accumulator. The front end function calls the recursive function to get a value, and then creates the shared ptr object for its return. The recursive function is "hidden" in the sense that it is not called directly.

Comment: @KennyOstrom makes sense. Though, I need `tail` to be a `shared_ptr` in order to reuse tail of list and have proper memory management. I will need to create this pointers afterwards and list should not be const in order to allow this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Answer

Short answer is: yes and no.

Shared pointer in C++ doesn't break tail call optimization,
but it complicates creation of such recursive function, that can be converted to loop by compiler.

## Details

### Avoiding stack overflow during recursive construction of a long list

I've recalled that `shared_ptr` has a destructor and C++ has RAII.
This makes construction of optimizable tail call harder, as it was discussed in [Can Tail Call Optimization and RAII Co-Exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17792887/can-tail-call-optimization-and-raii-co-exist) question.

@KennyOstrom has proposed to use an ordinary pointer to solve this problem

```
static const List* insertBulk_(unsigned amount, const List* tail=nullptr) {
    return amount? insertBulk_(amount - 1, new List{tail})
                 : tail;
}
```

The following constructor is used

```
List(const List* tail): tail{tail} {}
```

When `tail` of `List` is an instance of `shared_ptr`, tail call is successfully optimized.

### Avoiding stack overflow during destruction

Custom destruction strategy is needed.
Fortunately, `shared_ptr` allows us to set it,
so I've hidden destructor of `List` by making it `private`,
and use this for list destruction

```
static void destroy(const List* list) {
    if (!list) return;

    shared_ptr<const List> tail = list->tail;
    delete list;
    for (; tail && tail.use_count() == 1; tail = tail->tail);
}
```

Constructor should pass this destruction function to `tail` initialization list

```
List(const List* tail): tail{tail, List::destroy} {}
```

### Avoiding memory leak

In the case of exceptions I'll not have proper cleanup, so the problem's not solved yet.
I want to use `shared_ptr` because it's safe, but now I don't use it for current list head until the end of construction.

It's needed to watch the "naked" pointer until it's wrapped into shared pointer, and free it in the case of emergency.
Let's pass a reference to tail pointer instead of a pointer itself to `insertBulk_`.
This will allow the last good pointer to be visible outside of the function

```
static const List* insertBulk_(unsigned amount, const List*& tail) {
    if (!amount) {
        const List* result = tail;
        tail = nullptr;
        return result;
    }
    return insertBulk_(amount - 1, tail = new List{tail});
}
```

Then analogue of `Finally` is needed in order to automate destruction of a pointer, which will leak in the case of exception

```
static const shared_ptr<const List> insertBulk(unsigned amount) {
    struct TailGuard {
        const List* ptr;
        ~TailGuard() {
            List::destroy(this->ptr);
        }
    } guard{};
    const List* result = insertBulk_(amount, guard.ptr);
    return amount? shared_ptr<const List>{result, List::destroy}
                 : nullptr;
}
```

## Solution

Now, I guess, the problem is solved:

- `g++` and `clang++` successfully optimize recursive creation of long lists;
- lists still use `shared_ptr`;
- ordinary pointers seem to be in safety.

### Source code

The final code is

```
#include <memory>
#include <cassert>

using std::shared_ptr;

class List {
    private:
        const shared_ptr<const List> tail;

        /**
         * I need a `tail` to be an instance of `shared_ptr`.
         * Separate `List` constructor was created for this purpose.
         * It gets a regular pointer to `tail` and wraps it
         * into shared pointer.
         *
         * The `tail` is a reference to pointer,
         * because `insertBulk`, which called `insertBulk_`,
         * should have an ability to free memory
         * in the case of `insertBulk_` fail
         * to avoid memory leak.
         */
        static const List* insertBulk_(unsigned amount, const List*& tail) {
            if (!amount) {
                const List* result = tail;
                tail = nullptr;
                return result;
            }
            return insertBulk_(amount - 1, tail = new List{tail});
        }
        unsigned size_(unsigned acc=1) const {
            return this->tail? this->tail->size_(acc + 1) : acc;
        }
        /**
         * Destructor needs to be hidden,
         * because it causes stack overflow for long lists.
         * Custom destruction method `destroy` should be invoked first.
         */
        ~List() {}
    public:
        /**
         * List needs custom destruction strategy,
         * because default destructor causes stack overflow
         * in the case of long lists:
         * it will recursively remove its items.
         */
        List(const List* tail): tail{tail, List::destroy} {}
        List(const shared_ptr<const List>& tail): tail{tail} {}
        List(const List&) = delete;
        List() = delete;

        unsigned size() const {
            return this->size_();
        }

        /**
         * Public iterface for private `insertBulk_` method.
         * It wraps `insertBulk_` result into `shared_ptr`
         * with custom destruction function.
         *
         * Also it creates a guard for tail,
         * which will destroy it if something will go wrong.
         * `insertBulk_` should store `tail`,
         * which is not yet wrapped into `shared_ptr`,
         * in the guard, and set it to `nullptr` in the end
         * in order to avoid destruction of successfully created list.
         */
        static const shared_ptr<const List> insertBulk(unsigned amount) {
            struct TailGuard {
                const List* ptr;
                ~TailGuard() {
                    List::destroy(this->ptr);
                }
            } guard{};
            const List* result = insertBulk_(amount, guard.ptr);
            return amount? shared_ptr<const List>{result, List::destroy}
                         : nullptr;
        }
        /**
         * Custom destruction strategy,
         * which should be called in order to delete a list.
         */
        static void destroy(const List* list) {
            if (!list) return;

            shared_ptr<const List> tail = list->tail;
            delete list;

            /**
             * Watching references count allows us to stop,
             * when we reached the node,
             * which is used by another list.
             *
             * Also this prevents long loop of construction and destruction,
             * because destruction calls this function `destroy` again
             * and it will create a lot of redundant entities
             * without `tail.use_count() == 1` condition.
             */
            for (; tail && tail.use_count() == 1; tail = tail->tail);
        }
};

int main() {
    /**
     * Check whether we can create multiple lists.
     */
    const shared_ptr<const List> list{List::insertBulk(1E6)};
    const shared_ptr<const List> longList{List::insertBulk(1E7)};
    /**
     * Check whether we can use a list as a tail for another list.
     */
    const shared_ptr<const List> composedList{new List{list}, List::destroy};
    /**
     * Checking whether creation works well.
     */
    assert(list->size() == 1E6);
    assert(longList->size() == 1E7);
    assert(composedList->size() == 1E6 + 1);
    return 0;
}
```

### Shorter version of the source code

The `List` class without comments and checks in `main` function

```
#include <memory>

using std::shared_ptr;

class List {
    private:
        const shared_ptr<const List> tail;

        static const List* insertBulk_(unsigned amount, const List*& tail) {
            if (!amount) {
                const List* result = tail;
                tail = nullptr;
                return result;
            }
            return insertBulk_(amount - 1, tail = new List{tail});
        }
        ~List() {}
    public:
        List(const List* tail): tail{tail, List::destroy} {}
        List(const shared_ptr<const List>& tail): tail{tail} {}
        List(const List&) = delete;
        List() = delete;

        static const shared_ptr<const List> insertBulk(unsigned amount) {
            struct TailGuard {
                const List* ptr;
                ~TailGuard() {
                    List::destroy(this->ptr);
                }
            } guard{};
            const List* result = insertBulk_(amount, guard.ptr);
            return amount? shared_ptr<const List>{result, List::destroy}
                         : nullptr;
        }
        static void destroy(const List* list) {
            if (!list) return;

            shared_ptr<const List> tail = list->tail;
            delete list;

            for (; tail && tail.use_count() == 1; tail = tail->tail);
        }
};
```