# How does C++ compiler optimize stack allocation?

Tags: c++, memory, optimization, stack, compiler-optimization

I find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17792887/can-tail-call-optimization-and-raii-co-exist) and write some tests like this:

[image]

I am expecting compiler makes a TCO on `foo3`, that destroys `sp` first and invokes `func` with a simple jump that would not create stack frame. But it is not happening. The program runs into `func` at (assembly code) line 47 with a `call` and clean `sp` object after that. The optimization will not happen even I clear `~Simple()`.

So, how can I trigger TCO in this case?

Comment: Dude, you need to look at some assembly directly instead of looking at print statements. The very presence of print statements might be changing how the optimizations go down. I recommend https://godbolt.org/.

Comment: You can not reliably perform arithmetic operations on two unrelated pointers like you do in e.g. the `print_mem` function. That way lies [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Comment: @NirFriedman Thanks for advice. I have just tried it and updated my question.

Comment: It would be easier for everyone, if you would share (button on the right hand side at godbolt.org) the link and not the picture

Answer (score 1):

First, note that the example has a double-free bug. If the move-constructor is called, `sp.buffer` is not set to `nullptr` as it must be, so two pointers to the buffer now exist to be later deleted. A simpler version which manages the pointer correctly is:

```
struct Simple {
  std::unique_ptr<int[]> buffer {new int[1000]};
};
```

With that fix, let's inline almost everything and see what `foo3` really does in all its glory:

```
using func_t = std::function<int(Sample&&)>&&;
int foo3(func_t func) {
  int* buffer1 = new int[1000]; // the unused local
  int* buffer2 = new int[1000]; // the call argument
  if (!func) {
    delete[] buffer2;
    delete[] buffer1;
    throw bad_function_call;
  }
  try {
    int retval = func(buffer2); // <-- the call
  } catch (...) {
    delete[] buffer2;
    delete[] buffer1;
    throw;
  }
  delete[] buffer2;
  delete[] buffer1;
  return retval;              // <-- the return
}
```

The case of `buffer1` is straightforward. It is an unused local, and the only side effects are allocation and deallocation, which compilers are allowed to skip. An intelligent enough compiler could completely remove the unused local. clang++ 5.0 seems to accomplish this, but g++ 7.2 does not.

More interesting is `buffer2`. `func` takes a non-const rvalue reference. It can modify the argument. For example, it may move from it. But it may not. The temporary may still own a buffer which must be deleted after the call and `foo3` must do that. The call is **not** a tail call.

As observed, we get closer to a tail call by simply leaking the buffer:

```
struct Simple {
    int* buffer = new int[1000];
};
```

That's cheating a bit because a big part of the question is about tail call optimization in the face of nontrivial destructors. But let's entertain this. As observed, this alone does not result in a tail call.

To start with, note that passing by reference is a fancy form of passing by pointer. The object still must exist somewhere, and that's on the stack in the caller. Needing to keep the caller's stack alive and nonempty during the call will rule out tail call optimization.

To enable a tail call, we want to pass `func`'s arguments in registers, so it doesn't have to live in `foo3`'s stack. This suggests we should pass by value:

```
int foo2(Simple); // etc.
```

The SysV ABI dictates that to be passed in a register, it needs to be trivially copyable, movable, and destructible. Being a struct wrapping an `int*`, we have that covered. Fun fact: we can't use a `std::unique_ptr` here with a no-op deleter because that is not trivially destructible.

Even so, we still don't see a tail call. I do not see a reason preventing it, but I'm not an expert. Replacing the `std::function` with a function pointer does result in a tail call. The `std::function` has one extra argument in the call and has a conditional throw. Is it possible those make it difficult enough to optimize?

Anyways, with a function pointer, g++ 7.2 and clang++ 5.0 do the tail call:

```
struct Simple {
  int* buffer = new int[1000];
};

int foo2(Simple sp) {
  return sp.buffer[std::rand()];
}

using func_t = int (*)(Simple);
int foo3(func_t func) {
  return func(Simple());
}
```

But this is leaky. Can we do better? There is ownership underlying this type, and we want to pass it from `foo3` to `func`. But types with nontrivial destructors cannot be passed in arguments. This means an RAII type like `std::unique_ptr` will not get us there. Using a concept from the GSL, we can at least express the ownership:

```
template<class T> using owner = T;
struct Simple {
  owner<int*> buffer = new int[1000];
};
```

Then we can hope that static analysis tools now or in the future can detect that `foo2` is accepting ownership but never deleting `buffer`.